# What is the indexing searching algorithm that is used in Intellij IDE / Android Studio / Entrian, for Instant File Content Search?

Tags: algorithm, intellij-idea, search, indexing

It is really fast, it can show the result instantly as you type.
what are the indexing / searching algorithms used?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information here https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/indexing_and_psi_stubs.html